# I'm getting wrong String value

Tags: java

```
void displayId(PrintWriter stdOut, StringResources resources, IPatchBundle group, String[] ids){


        for(int i=0;i<ids.length;i++)
                System.out.println("Mids from cmdMds"+ids);
}
```

The above code produces `[Ljava.lang.String;@152cf21`.
I tried putting `.toString()` too, still getting the same. Please help me to get the actual value.

Comment: This *IS* the actual value. BTW, how many lines does it print?

Comment: You are still lying about your output. I feel that such unpolite questions should not be answered.

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
System.out.println("Mids from cmdMds"+ids);
```

To

```
System.out.println("Mids from cmdMds"+ids[i]);
```

You're trying to print the whole array each time, not the individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
System.out.println("Mids from cmdMds"+ids[i]);
```

You want to print the array elements `ids[i]`, not the array itself `ids.toString()`.

`[Ljava.lang.String;@152cf21` is decoded as:

- `[` - array
- `L` - of object
- `java.lang.String` - with class java.lang.String
- `;` - end of type signature
- `@152cf21` - `hashCode()` as hex

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.out.println("Mids from cmdMds"+ids[i]);
```